# "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION:Week: invalid date: Fri Jun 29 00:00:00 GMT 14 Error fields: Week__c "

Tags: data-loader, error

I am getting below error when I am trying to insert records using data loader.I see file contains Week__c column with value as 6/29/14 and Week__c is Date field in the custom object.What may be the issue ?

> "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION:Week: invalid date: Fri Jun 29 00:00:00 GMT 14
>   Error fields: Week__c "

[image]

Answer (score 1):

sf dev, please see the [Date Formats and Date Literals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) page for details on how the string value needs to be formatted. For example, if you're trying to load June 29, 2014 into a Date field, the value needs to be written as "2014-06-29".

Comment: Thanks Marty.I am trying to load date field as 6/29/2014.I have updated my question with pic.

Comment: Hello, sf dev, as I said you cannot load the date as 6/29/2014. You have to reformat the cell to render the value in **YYYY-MM-DD** format. See this screenshot for the custom number format used in Excel: http://screencast.com/t/xg0NAjXMH6